# Php manually select and uploaded files are stored into google drive

Tags: php, google-drive-api

This is my PHP code.This script is almost working fine when already set and created local files are uploaded automatically i am unable to select and browse the files so i need to browse and select the local files manually and stored those files in google drive.Is it possible to use Google drive api (with PHP) to open and browse local files or documents uploaded to google drive?

```
     <?php 
    session_start(); 
    $url_array = explode('?', 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); $url =
    $url_array[0]; 
    require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php'; 
    require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php'; 

    $client = new Google_Client(); 
    $client->setClientId('client ID');
    $client->setClientSecret('Secret code');
    $client->setRedirectUri($url);
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive')); 

    if(isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $_SESSION['accessToken'] = $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        header('location:'.$url);exit; 
    } elseif (!isset($_SESSION['accessToken'])) {
        $client->authenticate(); 
    } 
    $files= array(); $dir = dir('files'); 
    while ($file = $dir->read()) {
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
            $files[] = $file;
        } 
    } 
    $dir->close(); 
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['accessToken']);
        $service = new Google_DriveService($client);
        $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $file = new Google_DriveFile();

        foreach ($files as $file_name) {
            $file_path = 'files/'.$file_name;
            $mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $file_path);
            $file->setTitle($file_name);
            $file->setDescription('This is a '.$mime_type.' document');
            $file->setMimeType($mime_type);
            $service->files->insert(
                $file,
                array(
                    'data' => file_get_contents($file_path),
                    'mimeType' => $mime_type
                )
            );
        }
        finfo_close($finfo);
        header('location:'.$url);exit; 
    }     include 'index.phtml'; Index.phtml

<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="es">  <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Google Drive Example App</title>  </head>  <body>
     <ul>
     <?php foreach ($files as $file) { ?>
         <li><?php echo $files; ?></li>
     <?php } ?>
     </ul>
     <form method="post" action="<?php echo $url; ?>">

         <input type="submit" value="enviar" name="submit">
     </form>  </body> </html>
```

Index.phtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="es">
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Google Drive Example App</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <ul>
     <?php foreach ($files as $file) { ?>
         <li><?php echo $files; ?></li>
     <?php } ?>
     </ul>
     <form method="post" action="<?php echo $url; ?>">

         <input type="submit" value="enviar" name="submit">
     </form>
 </body> </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because [PHP is for server-side scripting](http://php.net/manual/en/intro-whatcando.php). It doesn't cover the User Interface.

I think what you need in this situation is a UI that presents you with an upload window. With this window, you'll be able to select files from your computer and upload them to your Google Drive. For this purpose, Google Drive's [Picker API](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#hiworld) will be of great use to you.